# Time complexity of birthday attack type problem

Tags: complexity, birthday-attack

I have two sorted lists: $A=\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1, \ldots, b_m\}$. 
I know that the probability of $a_i=b_j$ is $c$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1\leq j \leq m$.

The time complexity of finding all $a_i=b_j$ is 
$mnc$. Why?

Comment: So you need the intersection of two lists. If $n$ is close to $m$ then the complexity to find the intersection is $O(m+n).$ If $n\ll m$ then applying binary search you get $O(n\log{m}).$ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993655/find-common-elements-in-2-sorted-arrays